# make python interactive popup in a seperate window in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I run my python code in vscode so I can see output as I move along.  However, my work monitors in the office aren't the largest and so I don't have a ton of real estate to operate on.

Is it possible so that the output from my .py file appears in a physically separate window?  For example, my main vscode is on monitor #1 giving me plenty of real estate to type my code?  And when I hit `SHIFT+ENTER`  on something like `5+7` that I see this output in physically separate window  on monitor B?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the interactive window, using the `Jupyter: Create Interactive Widow` command to open the window. Or use the right-click menu to run code in an interactive window.

[image]

[image]

If you debug the file, use the following *launch.json*. Among them, the `"console"` configuration controls the output terminal, and the configuration as `"externalTerminal"` will open the external terminal.

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]